# Passing props to NextJS Layout Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the layout component imported in the _app.js file:

Layout.js:

```js
const Layout = ({ children, webName, pageTitle }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <meta charSet='utf-8' />
        <meta
          name='viewport'
          content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'
        />
        <meta name='description' content='' />
        <meta name='author' content='Chris Achinga -> chrisdevcode.xyz' />
        <title>Feet Of Colors Foundation</title>
      </Head>
      <PageHeader webName={webName} pageTitle={pageTitle} />
      <NavBar webName={webName} />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

The _app.js:

```js
import Layout from '@/layout/Layout'
import '@/styles/globals.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I have different pages that I would love to pass different values to webName and pageTitle props, without using the `Layout` component in each file.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pages/_app.tsx`:

```
import type { InferGetServerSidePropsType, NextPage } from 'next';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

export type NextPageWithLayout<Props extends (args: any) => any> = NextPage<InferGetServerSidePropsType<Props>> & {
    getLayout?: (page: React.ReactElement, props: InferGetServerSidePropsType<Props>) => React.ReactNode;
};

export type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
    Component: NextPageWithLayout<any>;
};

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? (page => page);

    return (
        <div className="root">
            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />, pageProps)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

`pages/index.tsx`:

```
import type { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import type { NextPageWithLayout } from '~/pages/_app';

import { Layout } from '~/layouts/custom-layout';

export const getServerSideProps = (async () => {
    // ... query your data

    return {
        props: {
            data,
        },
    };
}) satisfies GetServerSideProps;

const IndexPage: NextPageWithLayout<typeof getServerSideProps> = props => {};

IndexPage.getLayout = (page, props) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>;

export default IndexPage;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can make use of `getServerSideProps` to pass data to your `Layout`
 The data returned by `getServerSideProps` is passed as props to the page. And this same props is accessible in `_app.js`, so you can pass it to the layout.

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    // here you pass the pageProps to the layout
    <Layout pageProps={pageProps}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

In your `Layout` component :

```js
export default function Layout({ pageProps, children }) {
  console.log(pageProps); // see pageProps here
  return (
    <>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Finally in your Page :

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      webName: "name",
      pageTitle: "title"
    },
  };
}
```