# How to pass props from layout.js to page.js in Next.js 13 folder-based routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Next.js **13** operates on a folder-based routing system, where the folder structure itself defines the routing.

- For example, the layout.js file, located directly under the app folder, includes components and styles that are shared across multiple pages.

Here's a folder structure on my project (The parent folder containing package.json etc and unnecessary files are omitted.) :

```
app
  ├── (DropDownPages)/
  │   ├── layout.js ------ (2) * problem (parent component)
  │   ├── bookmark/
  │   │    └── page.js --- (3) (children component)
  │   └── product/
  │        └── page.js --- (3) (children component)
  │
  │ 
  ├── layout.js   ---- (1) 
  └── page.js
```

(1) app/layout.js

In the `layout.js file --- (1)` just under app folder, I have added a Header and Footer and pages within  tags.

```js
import './globals.css'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import { Providers } from './redux/provider'

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="ko">
      <Providers>
      <body>
        <Header />
          <main>{children}</main>
        <Footer />
      </body>
      </Providers>
    </html>
  )
}
```

(2) app/(DropDownPages)/layout.js

And within it, I have created a fixed category section at the top of the main page using another `layout.js --- (2)` in (DropDownPages) folder which is a parent folder for `bookmark/` and `product/`.

[Image of the category component on my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoyF0.jpg)

```js
"use client"

import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState } from "react";

const 전체 = 'all'
const 상품 = 'product'
const 카테고리 = 'category'
const 기획전 = 'exhibition'
const 브랜드 = 'brand'

.
.
.

export default function Category({ children }) {
 
  const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = useState(null);

  const handleTitleClick = (menu) => {
    setSelectedMenu(menu);
  }

  return (
    <Section>

      <nav className="flex justify-center items-center mt-6 mb-6">
        <MenuBox onClick={() => handleTitleClick(전체)}} >
          <ImageWrapper><StyledImage src="/전체.png" /></ImageWrapper>
          <Title>전체</Title>
        </MenuBox>

        <MenuBox onClick={() => handleTitleClick(상품)}} >
          <ImageWrapper><StyledImage src="/상품.png" /></ImageWrapper>
          <Title>전체</Title>
        </MenuBox>

        <MenuBox onClick={() => handleTitleClick(카테고리)}} >
          <ImageWrapper><StyledImage src="/카테고리.png" /></ImageWrapper>
          <Title>전체</Title>
        </MenuBox>

        <MenuBox onClick={() => handleTitleClick(기획전)}} >
          <ImageWrapper><StyledImage src="/기획전.png" /></ImageWrapper>
          <Title>전체</Title>
        </MenuBox>

        <MenuBox onClick={() => handleTitleClick(브랜드)}} >
          <ImageWrapper><StyledImage src="/브랜드.png" /></ImageWrapper>
          <Title>전체</Title>
        </MenuBox>
      </nav>

      <Main>
          {
            children
          }
      </Main>    

      </Section>

  )
}
```

**And here's the problem I'm struggling with :**

The problem arises I tried to pass the prop -selectedMenu- to children (`page.js --- (3)` ) when clicking on a specific category button in the `layout.js file. ---(2)`

So below is one of the child component in `app/(DropDowns)/product/page.js`

```js
"use client";

import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";


// I want to get the props -selectedMenu- from its parent -layout.js ---(2) - 
export default function Product({selectedMenu}) {       

console.log(selectedMenu) // undefined

.
.
.
.
```

While there are alternative solutions such as creating components and importing them into the page components or using Redux for global data management as usual, but I'm digging in exploring a solution that leverages the folder-based routing structure.

I have already attempted a solution mentioned in a Stack Overflow post [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644509/passing-props-to-nextjs-layout-component) where I tried to make a clone children with some props to pass, but it didn't work. (Maybe the way I tried could be wrong.)

```
// layout.js ---(2)

.
.
.
      <Main>
          {
            React.cloneElement(children, {selectedMenu: selectedMenu}, null)
          }
      </Main>    
.
.
.
```

> For more information, here's my code on my [Github account](https://github.com/Doyu-Lee/fe-sprint-coz-shopping/tree/seona/readme_add).

Comment: Have you considered creating a context instead of passing the props down?

Comment: I'm curious if there are any other approaches to passing props without relying on Redux or React's Context API. I'd like to explore different methods for passing data down the component tree in a more efficient manner. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Lee, welcome to the forum! Please go through the answer to the linked thread. Let us know if you think it does not answer your question. We will reopen it if it doesn't.